# What's the IPC mechanism between Nginx and backend server?

Tags: ruby, node.js, nginx, webserver, ipc

Nginx transfers requests to other backend servers, such as Thin(Ruby server), or Node.js server, or Tomcat, then **What's the IPC mechanism between them**?

Shared memory?
Socket (even in same machine)?
Pipe?
Standard IO? (For CGI or FastCGI, it is)

Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your setup, it my use Unix Sockets or TCP.

This will use TCP:

```
upstream my_site {
  server 127.0.0.1:9292;
}
```

This will use Unix Socket:

```
upstream my_site {
  server unix://path/to/socket;
}
```